# Log4j not writing System.out to the file

Tags: windows, tomcat, console, log4j

I have setup log4j with tomcat6 on Windows 2008. The statements are being logged to the log file, but `System.out` calls are not being logged.

When I run `tomcat6.exe` from command prompt, the `System.out` calls are displayed on the prompt, but the same is not logged in the log file.

I have defined a `ConsoleAppender` and `Filelogger` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

  <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true" threshold="debug">
      <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout">
    </layout>
      </appender>

      <appender name="CATALINA" class="org.apache.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender">
      <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.log"/>
              <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true"/>   
      <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/> 
      <param name="MaxRollFileCount" value="100"/>
      <param name="ScavengeInterval" value="30000"/>
      <param name="BufferedIO" value="false"/>
      <param name="CompressionAlgorithm" value="ZIP"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a} %c%n \r%p: %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    </appender>

<logger name="org.apache" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CATALINA" />
</logger>

    <root>
            <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your above log4j configuration you are creating a [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/ConsoleAppender.html) which logs all your messages to standard out. Which is the same location as the System.out.println() calls. Now when you created the 2nd Appender ([FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html)) you are no longer writing to standard out, but now writing to file.

I would suggest changing your system.out.println() calls to use [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) calls [error(), info(), debug() etc..]

```
public class MyClass{
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

 public MyClass(){
    logger.debug("Hello World");
 }
}
```

By doing this you wont be mixing and matching your log4j with your standard out calls and then can configure your application as needed between console and file writing. A good benefit to using a Logger over the System.out calls is that they are configurable at runtime and can log messages at various levels.

**Edit as per comments**

Tomcat by default logs the stdout messages to `%tomcat_home%/logs/catalina.out` (name may differ slightly per tomcat specs) Tomcat uses a logging framework called [JULI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) to performs its basic logging operations. If you simply want the log to be written somewhere else then the tomcat folder, you can do that by editing the file 
%tomcat_home/conf/logging.properties

Another scenario you may want to tackle is redirecting the stdout completely. This is frowned upon but can be done. If you look at the file catalina.bat (or .sh in unix) you will see the startup option of LOGGING_MANAGER which will override the default JULI implementation. I have never used this option so you would need to research it in more depth. To understand JULI more read Apache's [Wiki article](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Sean. Actually the output I want to be logged appear alongside following log4j info on console: log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="debug".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.apache] additivity to [false].
log4j: Level value for org.apache is  [INFO].
It would be great if I could direct this logger to a log file. Thanks

Comment: so it is the log4j initialization messages you are looking to log?

Comment: if it is the standard out message you want, by default they should be logged under %tomcat%/logs/catalina.out,  otherwise you need to look at redirecting the stdout. tomcat by default logs the standard out to the above mentioned file

Comment: The reason why we are using log4j instead of juli is that juli doesn't provide log compression (I looked everywhere if it does). The statements log using juli are logged into my current log4j log file as well, but surprisingly some of the output shows up only on console (like the log4j info I pasted above). Which made me wonder if there is a logger I can define that would tap these statements (even if I have to include log4j info messages).

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging) gives a hint about how to do this, but it's a little cryptic. In short:

- Open the context.xml file for your tomcat config. For me, developing inside Eclipse, this is inside my Eclipse Workspace under

> \Workspace\Project\Servers\Server-name-config\config.xml

There's also a global tomcat version under, which is worth a shot

> \tomcat\conf\context.xml

- Add swallowOutput="true" to the context as below

  ```
  <context swallowOutput="true">
  ```
- (Optional I think) Set up your application logging. I've used LogBack in my application, but I'm not sure it's relevant as this goes through the internal Tomcat logging not your application logging
- In my tomcat.logging property I have the following log configuration lines. These lines define the log file that my System.out statements go to, though other people have said it goes to their catalina.out file

  ```
  2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
  2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
  2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
  ```
- Now when you do a System.out.println it should appear in your localhost.log file as it does for me, though as I said some people have said it goes into catalina.log